# How to get data inside a Nested Array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, nested

const datafromback=[[{name:ravi}],[{}],[{}],[{}]]

I want to access ravi. Can anyone help me how can i see ravi in my console.with dealing with nested arrays

I not getting approach but i can use map to map through datafromback array but don't know how to get inside it

Answer (score 1):

You can use 0 index

```js
const datafromback = [[{ name: 'ravi' }], [{}], [{}], [{}]]

const dataFrom = (arr, nameRavi) => {
    let result
    arr.forEach((ele) => {
        if (ele[0].name === nameRavi) result = ele[0].name
    })
    return result
}

console.log(dataFrom(datafromback, 'ravi'))
```

Answer (score 0):

one possible way is to use `flat` first to remove nested array

```
const datafromback=[[{name:ravi}],[{}],[{}],[{}]]
const flatternArray = datafromback.flat() // [{name:ravi},{},{},{}]
flatternArray.map(item => {
    console.log(item.name) // 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this :

```js
const datafromback=[[{name:'ravi'}],[{}],[{}],[{}]]

const [{name}] =  datafromback.find(data=>data.find(item=>item.name === 'ravi')?.name === 'ravi')

    console.log(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a recursive function if you have non-fixed dimensions array :

```js
const handle = e => {
  if (Array.isArray(e))
    return e.map(handle)
  else {
    console.log(e.name)
  }
}

handle(array)
```

Or if you know the dimensions, you can use nested for loops like so :

```js
// example for 2 dimensions
for (let y = 0; y < array.length; y++)
  for (let x = 0; x < array[y].length; x++)
    console.log(array[y][x].name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey so what you have above is a 2D object array. if you just want to console you can use a nested forEach to get the key value, like this.

```
datafromback.forEach(data => {
  //this is the nested array that contains the objects
  data.forEach(obj => {
    //here you can access the actual object
    if (obj?.name) console.log(obj.name);
  });
});
```

this will return the value of key (name) if present ie ravi in your case.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```js
const datafromback = [[{ name: 'ravi' }], [{}], [{}], [{}]];
const names = [];

datafromback.map((items) => {
  items.map((item) => {
    if (item?.name) names.push(item?.name);
  });
});
console.log(names);
```